# Uses of Multi-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Well I am beginning to learn Java as I have an android app i would like to develop and i have come across the topic of multi-dimensional arrays. I have noticed the only use is to draw simple tables. Is there any other use and is this a necessary topic for the future.

-K.B

Comment: Multidimensional-arrays are arrays of arrays.. if you need more than one array an easy way to store them is in an array.. I find it hard to believe you see no use for this

Answer (score 2):

There are several "real life usages" of multi-dimension arrays. Let me use images to explain:

a greyscale image of 4x4 pixels can be represented like this:

```
int[][] myArray = {  {236, 189, 189,   0},
                     {236,  80, 189, 189},
                     {236,   0, 189,  80},
                     {236, 189, 189,  80}  };
```

it would give this output, if parsed into an image:

[image: grid]

However, if you wanted actual colors instead of greyscales, you would probably have to define a set of RGB or CMYK values for every single pixel. In other words, you would need an array of values for each pixel. And there you have an example of a three dimensional array.

This short examples should give you a little more insight of possible uses of multi-dimensional arrays, but bear in mind that the usage areas are countless, so a complete, or even an attempted thourough coverage of the subject, is pretty much impossible.

You also ask "is this a necessary topic for the future." I very rarely use arrays directly at all in my day to day coding. I do however use a lot of different collections, which builds upon array architecture. Also, the understanding of multi-dimensional arrays helps me build collections of multi-dimensional objects (Objects containing other Objects, containing even more Objects etc.) I would definitely reccommend learning about Collections.

Answer (score 1):

Their use is wherever you need information in more than one-dimension (single array). There is no real 'when' or 'where' to use them. You use them where they're appropriate, a lot of situations can use OOP to navigate around Java n-dimensional arrays.

That's like asking me where `char` should be used or where `String` should be used... or when each should be used over each other. You use them if you need to.

Comment: And don't forget the use of the `Collection` types.

Answer (score 0):

Java array (and multi dimensional array) is a very nativ way of structuring data. In PHP there are very commonly used collection, but in Java not so, because there are some more specific collection implemented for some tipical problems. But behind the scene, these collection implementations uses native arrays. So, you need to know about arrays.